# Changes from stash are not applied to working copy. Why?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash

I did change to my file:

```
--- a/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI3.pm
+++ b/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI3.pm
@@ -396,6 +396,7 @@ sub _check_response {
     # Here we do not know what to do with all of this.
     # Thus we just say: Not Implemented
     # $c->stash->{ status } //=  404;
+    DB::x;
     $c->render( status => 501, data => '' );
 }
```

By when try to apply stash I get the error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI3.pm
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

But stash has no cross changes to same lines:

```
$ git stash show -p
--- a/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI3.pm
+++ b/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI3.pm
@@ -452,6 +463,7 @@ sub validate_response {
     # NOTICE: Depending on status we will check normal or error response
     my $status =  $stash->{ status } //=  200;
     my $schema =  $stash->{ 'openapi3.schema' }{ responses };
+    $status =  'default'   if !$schema->{ $status };
     # TODO: Schema also not found for not found request:
     # Request which come to not defined path. In this case we should provide
     # something like default response, should not?
```

Why I get the error above? Why the changes in stash are just merged into working directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that there are outstanding changes to the file `OpenAPI3.pm` in your working directory.  Applying the stash directly would overwrite some of those changes, hence the error message:

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

The resolution for this follows the above message:

> Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.

You may either commit the changes, or make another stash.  Or, perhaps you don't need the changes, and a third option would be to just reset the file `OpenAPI3.pm` to the latest commit.

Comment: That seems redundant. Changes are not in conflict thus I expect it work like `patch` utility. We crate that patch from dirty working directory. And I do not see any problem to just apply that patch to clean or dirty directory